# Cleaning up my Meteor functions and queries

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have numerous client side functions including find() queries and date / time translations that I have listed in multiple places within my project. With Meteor, where is the best place to put these so I can eliminate redundancy and possible inconsistencies?

Also, how would then I reference, for example, a find() query? Would it be like this? Or is there a much better way of doing this altogether?

```
// JS file calling my re-usable function

Template.templatename.events({
  'click .class': function {
    var cats = function spaghetti();
    return cats;
  }
});

// JS file with re-usable functions

function spaghetti() {
  return Collection.find();
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-query-builder/

Comment: Thanks for the link! So there's no way to natively reach out to outside queries without building code (or installing a package) to support that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to return the collection in the click event?

If you meant helpers instead of events, you can do this:

```
/**
 * Only on catsList template
 */
Template.catsList.helpers({
  cats: function() {
    return Cats.find();
  }
})

/**
 * On all templates
 */
Template.registerHelper('cats', function() {
  return Cats.find();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) is what are you looking for, if you have for example, the same `Collection.find();` on 7 differents templates (for example), you can use this functionality from `meteor-templates-extension`.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  {{> foo}}
  {{> foo2}}
</body>

<template name="foo">
  {{bar}}
  <button type="button">Click</button>
</template>

<template name="foo2">
  {{bar}} 2
  <button type="button">Click 2</button>
</template>
<!-- and so on -->
```

**JS**

```
Template.foo.helpers = function () {
 thisHelperIsAvaibleEverywhere:function(){
     return "Test";
  }
};

Template.foo.events({
  'click button': function (event, template) {
    console.log("foo button clicked");
  }
});

Template.foo2.inheritsHelpersFrom("thisHelperIsAvaibleEverywhere");
Template.foo2.inheritsEventsFrom("foo");
```

So now the both templates `Foo and Foo2` can use the same helper, and they will use the same event named `foo`

Take a look and tell me if works